# apex:outputpanel onclick not click-able?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

**Background**

1) User enters in data

2) Presses a button (command link styled as a button) which does an upsert to the database.

I would like to mimic the native lightning green bar that displays on success.

**What I have**

1) The button to upload the data

```
<apex:commandLink action="{!updateInfo}" value="Save" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-float--left "reRender="outerPanel"/>
```

2) The following method on the controller

```
public void updateInfo(){
    try {
        update info;
        uploadStatus = True;
    } catch (Exception ex){
        uploadStatus = False;
        errMessage = ex.getMessage();
        System.debug('Error message' + ex);
    }
}
```

3) The following outputpanel that is rerendered on click of the button from 1.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="rerenderTopPanel" rerender="outerPanel"/>
<apex:outputPanel id='outerPanel' onclick="resetPanel">
    <apex:outputPanel style="background-color:green;width:100%;padding:10px;" rendered="{!uploadStatus}" onclick="resetPanel">Upload Successful!</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

4) and the following javascript

```
<script>
    function resetPanel(){
            uploadStatus = false;
            rerenderTopPanel();
   }
</script>
```

**Problem**

Even though I have an onclick on both the outerPanel and the thing nested inside it on 4, I can't seem to click on it to reset the value to false. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used and refactored your code to make it workable. Rather than javascript function to call, here calling the controller method via `actionSupport` and it works perfectly.

**Controller**

```
public class OutputController
{
    public Boolean uploadStatus {get;set;}
    public void updateInfo(){
        try {
            uploadStatus = True;
        } catch (Exception ex){
            uploadStatus = False;            
            System.debug('Error message' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void resetStatus()
    {
        uploadStatus = false;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="OutputController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandLink action="{!updateInfo}" value="Save" 
        reRender="outerPanel" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-float--left "/>

        <apex:outputPanel id="outerPanel">          
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!uploadStatus}" style="background-color:green;width:100%;padding:10px;">
                <apex:outputText value="Upload Successful-{!uploadStatus}" />
                <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!resetStatus}"  rerender="outerPanel" />
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

This code is fully complied and you can add additional functionality based on your need, like `update info;` inside `updateInfo()` method.